# Let connected device know about the maximum 2.1A output of a USB port via software

Tags: usb, power-management

I am fairly technical and I was wondering if there are any software based hacks or modifications that I can apply to force the maximum of **2.1A** to be supplied through a USB port without the attached device first negotiating this over the data pins?

By default my MacBook Pro (15" Mid 2015) will only supply **500mA** through its USB ports if the device hasn't explicitly requested access to the additional **1600mA**. This is mostly a software limitation I believe, because the hardware will be just fine with supplying **2.1A**.

My question: Is it possible to make my MacBook Pro believe that the device has requested an additional **1600mA** without the need of dongles or other external devices (which I don't have with me now, while I need the power for my phone at the moment). I'm ok with importing `.kext` files or doing other kind of low-level (*read potentially risky*) modifications.

**EDIT:** After some inspection of the MacBook's schematic the power isn't actually being limited, its my phone not willing to take more power because the macbook hasn't indicated yet that its alright to do so. Chargers do this by applying a special voltage to both the D- D+ data pins of the USB port, is there any chance this is possible in any other way? Otherwise I assume this is a lost cause and I should look into breaking protocol from my phone by just telling its alright to consume more current.

I changed the question title to better reflect newfound information

Comment: >"This is mostly a software limitation I believe, because the hardware will be just fine with supplying 2.1A." Source?

Comment: Source is the macbook board schematic (820-00138 is used in this model), They power the USB ports from the PP5V_S4 line and its being limited by a TP2557DRB IC which is (As long as the system doesn't force it to be less) set to have a 2.2A power limit. Obviously can't share the direct schematic here but you can find it online

Comment: Do you have information that J4600 isn't responsible for the 500mA limit without assistance from the OS? I couldn't find detail on that part.

Comment: J4600 can't limit as its simply a connector. The limiting is setup at U4600 over Pin 5 (USB_ILIM), The maximum is set over resistors R4600/01. However I'm starting to think the system is actually not able to limit the current passing through, since USB_ILIM_R is not connected to anything other then a testpoint. I think I should tell me phone to just pull more current, instead of telling my macbook this. Another option would be to have the macbook announce its a charger over the USB D- D+ pins, but that would probably be near impossible :)

Comment: I'm wondering if something upstream is just cutting off vbus when it senses some current over 500mA. As you mention USB_ILIM_R is just a testpoint, it appears that U4600 isn't involved in limiting the current below 2.1A.

Comment: Its probably my phone being nice to the USB protocol by limiting its current to 500mA unless the device specifies it allows for more. Either the macbook should indicate it can provide more or I should see if I can tell my phone to just pull more current. (Android phone so I should ask a different place about it)

Comment: I can't speak for that particular device but my experience with Mac USB ports is that drawing more than 500mA causes the port to soft shutdown until there's no load on it anymore. It's not hard to test this if you have a non-powered USB hub and a few higher draw devices. The OS will definitely notify you of the USB port state, but I can't find any evidence that the soft-shutdown state isn't managed somewhere on the board.

Comment: It might have been like that on previous models, I'm unsure. But based on the schematic there is no way to disable just one USB port and no way to get individual USB port power draw.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a usb hub around to test? It might at least help narrow it down to definitely being either the mac or the phone.